# Flutter google map FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager

Tags: java, android, flutter

When google map trying rendering the android application down by FATAL EXCEPTION/

```
E/AndroidRuntime(16156): FATAL EXCEPTION: androidmapsapi-ZoomTableManager
E/AndroidRuntime(16156): Process: com.example.coffeetop, PID: 16156
E/AndroidRuntime(16156): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=12
E/AndroidRuntime(16156):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.ct.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215084@20.12.15 (120700-0):9)
E/AndroidRuntime(16156):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.cv.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215084@20.12.15 (120700-0):23)
E/AndroidRuntime(16156):    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.util.m.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@201215084@20.12.15 (120700-0):14)
E/AndroidRuntime(16156):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

I know google provided a solution here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/154855417. But i dont know how to fix it in Flutter app. Help please.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.
Just deleted app cache and reinstall app on emulator.